# Can't get past 401 Unauthorized Twitter streaming API Oauth

Tags: api, twitter, streaming

I am attempting to build a c# module to connect to the Twitter streaming API using OAuth (now the only option).  I have got to the point where my module will successfully access api urls using GET, but everything I do to try and make a POST request fails with a 401.

I have checked my signature is correct by using the OAuth Tool tab on the page for my Twitter App, and fixing the values for nonce and timestamp in my code.  I have curl for Windows set up and can verify that it works with the sample curl script generated by the OAuth tool (by the way, this needs some correction of the quotes to make it work for curl in Windows Cmd.  Get rid of single quotes on values that don't need them, use double quotes on anything that needs to be quoted, and on the Authorization header, use double quotes and escape double quotes within the header with a backslash).

I have even gone to the length of running curl in trace mode and outputting the bytes I send in the post body from my c# code and I can verify that they are the same.

I am trying to access 'https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json' using 'track=twitter' as the post body.  The headers are:

```
Accept: */*
User-Agent: curl/7.21.7(amd64-pc-win32) libcurl/7.21.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8rzlib/1.2.5
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: stream.twitter.com
Content-Length: 13
Connection: Keep-Alive
Authorization: OAuth <the oauth stuff>
```

I can't inspect the packets being sent to check on the wire that the requests are identical as they are of course SSL encoded.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got this to work.  Things that might help you if you have this kind of problem which I discovered:

1. I had a problem initially because I created a new nonce every time the bit of code was accessed.  This meant the nonce which was used in generating the signature key was different from the one in the header.  Obviously fail.
2. I then ran into the above problem.  What it was is that I was adding the OAuth header to my request AFTER I sent the request body.  For some reason it seems to send the request as soon as you write to the request stream for a POST.

It was very useful in finding 2. that I found out how to use Fiddler to trace web requests from code.  Essentially all you need to do is add this to your web.config:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy  proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

As soon as I tried to read the HTTPS request, Fiddler prompted me to install bits so it could decrypt the request, which I did and then I could see the exact request going down the wire.  I could compare this with what cURL was doing using

```
-x 127.0.0.1:8888
```

option.

However I then ran into a problem with my request timing out.  Which bizarrely enough was caused by the fact that Fiddler was proxying the response.  Once I took the above out of my web.config again it all worked.  Halleluja!